# How can I fix panniers that have got holes in

Tags: repair, panniers

I've got some Crosso panniers that have got quite a few holes in. I once fixed a drybag backpack with patches of leather and industrial strength glue which worked like a treat, but I've forgotten what glue it was (it came in a large tin and I spread it on with a knife)- it was in the textiles department at the uni I was studying in. Any advice / links / tricks would be great.

Comment: Needle and thread.  You can buy those and a small piece of "outdoor" fabric at a fabric store.

Comment: They are made of a plastic material so this method won't work.

Comment: Hard plastic or soft, pliable plastic?

Comment: You could try patches for an inflatable raft. Alternatively, take the bag to an outdoors shop and see what they'd recommend for patching similar materials. You can also duct tape in a patch of similar material as well.

Comment: ask in the DIY (hardware in USA) store for a glue that's suitable for plastic.

Comment: I used this industrial strength glue with large patches of leather which worked brilliantly, so the glue would have to glue leather onto plastic.

Comment: Duct Tape
////////////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sew your own patches on using canvas and high-strength thread. They even sell kevlar thread that's useful for this type of thing.

If it were my panniers and I prefer strong-but-ugly, then I would cut up an old inner tube and use those as my patch materials. There's a very strong contact cement called [Pliobond](http://www.hannarubbercompany.com/Adhesives_PLIOBOND.php) that you can use to glue pretty much any flexible material to another one.

You can even make your patches from leather (still using Pliobond) or canvas (ditto). I've bonded leather and rubber to steel/aluminum using Pliobond.

Or you can lame out and go to your local outdoor store that sells a broad variety of patch materials for backpacks and tents: http://www.rei.com/c/gear-repair

Many backpackers, for example, use "Shoe Goo" to not only repair their shoes (you can craft new soles with it) but also patch rather large holes in their backpacks. Sugru is also useful for this type of repair.

Comment: If you want to buy Pliobond in the EU/UK then Microtools is your source: http://www.micro-tools.de/en/Adhesives-Glue/Adhesive-Pliobond-3oz-Bottle.html?listtype=search&searchparam=pliobond

Comment: @Andrew Welch, Woolies also has a variety of contact adhesives: http://www.woolies-trim.co.uk/c-304-adhesive.aspx

Comment: woolies don't have any flexible adhesives.

Comment: Robokaren is Pliobond flexible?

Comment: Yes, you can use it to bond leather to plastic or nylon..

Comment: would this work? http://www.amazon.co.uk/flexible-suitable-glueing-leather-plastic/forum/Fx292N217S6Y5HZ/Tx3R1MY3CUXZK3T/1/ref=cm_cd_naredir?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00HVG6CBM&cdItems=25&cdNewQuestion=1&store=generic

Answer (score 2):

If you have water proof panniers made of soft plastic, patches made for fixing holes in bike tubes are really great (depending on the size of the holes in the panniers of course).

Comment: what about using old bits of bike tube or tyre?

Comment: @AndrewWelch tube patches are 2-component: one is on patch, other is the glue. For pieces of old tubes you will need a special glue.

Comment: Yeah but they vulcanise onto rubber, and the panniers are made of plastic so it would probably be better to use pliobond and innertube.