# Material to make patches to fix Crosso / Ortlieb style waterproof panniers?

Tags: touring

I've got some panniers to fix. I've bought some impact adhesive and I am working out which material to buy for the patches - will PVC ok ? or polyurethane or something else?
Has to be waterproof and strong and preferable available in yellow!

Comment: How big is the area you have to patch?

Comment: small but I want to use big patches like 10x10cm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Patching waterproof panniers](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1971/patching-waterproof-panniers)

Answer (score 2):

You could try an air bed repair kit? 
The patches are tough, the bond is flexible and air tight.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be yellow, waterproof, strong, and 10x10cm then the repair kit is replace the bag.

From a small hole Ortleib makes a repair kit

[Universal Fabric Patch Kit](http://www.ortliebusa.com/prodInfo.asp?pid=133&cid=2)

Comment: I want to avoid buying the kit.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the kit?  Why did you not state that in the question?

Comment: why would I ask the question if I wanted to use the kit.

Comment: The material Ortlieb use is the same that is used on lorries.

Comment: @carel thanks for the scientific answer there. I'll go and find out what that material is called now.